# Html select dropdown list - how to choose the selected value from server code

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a select list say of states in the country, which i have in a helper to include easily in any form. (removing most options to make it brief).

I have the value of the current selection stored in the database say "CA". How would i set selected="true" to option CA before rendering the list to the user?

```
@helper StateSelect(string name = "State")
    {
    <select name="@name" id="@name" class="required">
        <option value="">-- Select -- </option>
        <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
        <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
        <option value="CA">California</option>
        <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
        <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
        <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
        <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
        <option value="WA">Washington</option>
        <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
        <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>
}
```

Comment: Any reason you are reinventing wheels and not using the `DropDownListFor` helper to generate dropdownlists?

Comment: Not about reinventing wheels, it's more about using old code that i already have. I have a few select lists that i already have, didnt want to manually sit and convert all of them into ENUMs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Darin Dimitrov says, the built-in stuff would be better. However, if you do need to, I think you have a few options:

1. Add code like this to every line:

   - `<option value="CA" @(name == "CT" ? "selected=selected" : "")> Connecticut</option>`
2. Just re-add the selected item to the top of the list

   - This keeps the code cleaner, the selected option is just repeated at the top (and selected there), before the entire list